# How to use 2 DVI monitors with only 1 DVI port

Tags: hdmi, dvi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a DVI splitter cable on 1 DVI port?](https://superuser.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-use-a-dvi-splitter-cable-on-1-dvi-port)

Hello. I have 2 DVI monitors, and my computer only has 1 DVI jack. What sort of solutions are available (are there combiners/should I buy 3 DVI to HDMI cables and then buy a HDMI splitter)?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a DVI splitter cable on 1 DVI port?](http://superuser.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-use-a-dvi-splitter-cable-on-1-dvi-port) (@Eisaj: if that thread doesn't provide enough information, edit your question to say what you're still in doubt about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [USB to DVI](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=usb+to+dvi&x=0&y=0) converter to add a DVI monitor. I use an [IOGear](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016B6722) external video card (USB to DVI) to add a 21 inch screen to my laptop and it works well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it will work well. I think you need special hardware in the first place to split a digital signal, and then even if you do that, you will only be able to have a single screen output but being cloned by each monitor.

Comment: Why can't the hardware just split the outgoing info into two monitors, and then represent itself as one massive monitor to the computer? I'm sure this hardware exists, just don't know what it's called.

Comment: I don't think video cards support huge resolutions for one monitor. Especially if the video card doesn't have two outputs in the first place. What video card do you have if I may ask?