# Extended desktop with a Y-connector?

Tags: dvi, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a DVI splitter cable on 1 DVI port?](https://superuser.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-use-a-dvi-splitter-cable-on-1-dvi-port)

I have a Dell desktop with an ATI Radeon. The graphic card has a single DVI output and I am wondering if I could connect to it a second monitor to have an extended desktop (not a copy of the main monitor). If I buy a [Y-connector](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814998037) will it work or I have to buy another graphic card with a dual output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to buy a graphics card with a dual output.

Or possibly a second single-output card...

A splurged will just (I believe) give you the same image on each screen.

Answer (score 0):

The Y connector you specified is a DMS-59 to 2x DVI single link. a DMS-59 is a very different connector from a single-link adaptor and is usually used in environment where a small card (i.e. a single slot card needed to support 4 monitor / a low-profile card needed to support 2 monitor).

If you have an display card with DVI interface, a DMS-59 to 2x DVI single link adaptor is unsuitable for your use and is not compatible with your display card.