# GPU - Graphics Card with 2 DVI Outputs or 1 DVI Output and use a splitter

Tags: dvi, graphics, gpu

As the title says, I'm looking for a new computer and am trying to compare graphics cards. I see some of them have 2 DVI outputs on the card and I was wondering if there way any advantage of using this instead of using a DVI Splitter to use two monitors.

Is there any performance issues that would arise from using a splitter vs getting a dual-DVI graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DVI splitter will only allow you to have the same image on two monitors, where as a two-port DVI setup will allow you to have that, or independent images (resolutions, etc.) for each monitor (which is usually preferred).

For more info, perhaps check out this SU question: [How can I use a DVI splitter cable on 1 DVI port?](https://superuser.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-use-a-dvi-splitter-cable-on-1-dvi-port)

Comment: Is there *any* way to do an extended desktop. I have a setup at work(I'm not 100% now, but will check when I can) that I have 2 monitors setup on a single DVI port through a Y splitter that allows me to do an extended desktop.

Comment: It's probably not a DVI port on that machine. There are several low-profile video cards that use a single non-standard port that splits into two DVI ports (or two VGA, or one of each, etc.).  Many of them are about the same size/shape as DVI, but the pin density is much higher (doubled).

Comment: That could be it. I hadn't pulled it out because I didn't have a need to, but it looked the same size. Thanks for not treating me like an idiot :D