# 3 hdmi and 1 DVI from GTX 1050ti

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

I am attempting to hook up 4x aoc E2270Sw monitors into my system with an 4gb msi GTX 1050ti.

The issue I have is 3 of the monitors have hdmi inputs and 1 has dvi, where as the graphics card has 1x1.2 dp, 1xhdmi and 1xdvi.

Is it possible to get all 4 of the monitors connected as individual displays (not mirrored) and if so what equipment am I going to need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get all 4 of the monitors connected as individual displays (not mirrored) and if so what equipment am I going to need.

The specifications for your graphics card indicates it only support 3 displays.

> Maximum Displays 3

Source: [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti GAMING X 4G](https://us.msi.com/Graphics-card/GeForce-GTX-1050-Ti-GAMING-X-4G/Specification)

> I was told I could split the dp or dvi

If you split a DVI signal you would mirror the same display twice and you indicate you specifically do not want to do that.  HDMI unlike DisplayPort only supports one and video signal which means it cannot be used to accomplish your goal.

Since your monitors do not support DisplayPort you cannot leverage the fact.  Converting DisplayPort to HDMI would not work in a case like this.  [DMS-59](https://superuser.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-use-a-dvi-splitter-cable-on-1-dvi-port) can indeed do want you want but your hardware does not support it.

**What you want is not possible given the hardware you have.**  If you want to use 4 monitors you will need a card that has 4 video outputs.  You might actually have trouble finding a graphic cards with 4 video outputs, with enough outputs of the correct type, to support what you are trying to do.

Comment: I verified that every single 1050 Ti that MSI produces only supports 3 displays.  Since you did not provide the exact model, and I wanted to link to something, I took a wild guess.